# TouchKeyboard component doesn't always adopt process language

Tags: delphi, keyboard, virtual

I use delphi TTouchKeyboard component for typing on windows. The keyboard switches between different layouts for different languages on its own.
Now I would like to use different input languages in different processes. Therefore I check the process for its language when it is focused and change the keyboard layout if it doesn't fit. 
That works well with most of the languages, but for the Arabian language (and maybe some others, too), the layout won't adopt. 
The keyboard then shows another layout (the one of the process which was focused before), but in the destination process Arabian letters are typed.
Has anyone an explanation for this and can tell me how to make the keyboard language always fit the process language?

Below is the procedure which makes the keyboard layout fit the process layout:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplyToCurrentProcessLanguage;
var
Layout: Hkl;
MyHandle: THandle;
begin
  MyHandle := GetForegroundWindow;
  Layout := GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(MyHandle)) div 65536;
  ActivateKeyboardLayout(Layout, 0);
end;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, the `TTouchKeyboard` works fine with a keyboard layout of `AR`. Mind that while `GetKeyboardLayout` returns a `HKL`, you might need to call `LoadKeyboardLayout` for _your process_  first.

Comment: Also, why do you go such a weird way with determining the thread id for `GetKeyboardLayout`? You might as well pass `0` for "current thread"

Comment: I have to use it like this because I'm working in different processes. I want to get the HKL of the process with keyboard focus. GetKeyboardLayout(0) would return the keyboard layout of the keyboard process.